# What is the expected JSON serialization of 'oneof' protobuf field?

Tags: json, protocol-buffers

Assuming I have a .proto with structure like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
  ...
}
message Bar {
  ...
}

message Msg {
  string baz = 1;
  oneof some_union {
     Foo foo = 2;
     Bar bar = 3;
  }
}
```

What is the expected way to serialise a message of this kind ?
The [JSON Mapping](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json) section of the spec is not very clear.

I can see at least two ways to represent it, which is the right one ?

First way: have a single element at the "top level", ignore the others:

```
{
  "baz" : 0,
  "foo" : { ... }
}
```

Second way: have an "unmbrella" property with the name of the union, and give it a single field.

```
{
  "baz" : 0,
  "some_union": {
    "foo" : { .... }
  }
}
```

What should I expect ?

Comment: Should be easy enough to test with one of the Google's own implementations, but my guess would be the first one because that would match the way it is encoded in the binary representation.

Answer (score 3):

I write some test code, it shows the first is the right one.

Comment: Right, we took the same approach, and had different results with different implementations in different languages :D

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
{
  "baz" : 0,
  "some_union" : {
     "oneofKind: "foo",
     "foo" : {...}

   }
}
```